# clickhouse-server install failed on CentOS6 with libbfd package error

Tags: binutils, clickhouse

I'm testing clickhouse. Finally I installed ClickHouse on my virtual machine. But I've got some problem to make it.

--> Finished Dependency Resolution
Error: Package: clickhouse-server-1.1.54236-4.el6.x86_64 (clickhouse)
           Requires: libbfd-2.20.51.0.2-5.44.el6.so()(64bit)

But, I already have this "binutils-2.20.51.0.2-5.47". (More recent version)
[root@node01 ~]# rpm -qa | grep "binutils"
binutils-2.20.51.0.2-5.47.el6_9.1.x86_64

So, I removed binutils-2.20.51.0.2-5.47 and install binutils-2.20.51.0.2-5.44, it works well.

Is this common issue?

Thanks.
Chan.

Answer (score 0):

The BFD libraries are only intended for internal use by binutils and related tools.  There is no ABI stability even within the same release of CentOS (or Red Hat Enterprise Linux).  This is why the library name can change from minor release to minor release, breaking RPM dependencies in this way.

You need to talk to whoever builds clickhouse.  They need to bundle their own version of BFD if they truly need it, or use supported libraries such as libelf from elfutils if they need only a tiny subset.